# How to make Nautilus ask for confirmation before moving files?

Tags: linux, nautilus

I need Nautilus to ask for confirmation before moving files. How can I set it up to do that?

Comment: Which distribution of Linux?

Comment: I'm using Centos 6.4

Comment: Nautilus version would help a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't nautilus do that by default? I haven't used nautilus since the GNOME 3 debacle, so this could have changed. MATE's caja is forked from nautilus, though, and it prompts before replacing, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus allow users to create scripts for it. Create one for that, there are many tutorials about how to develop a simple script for nautilus.